# Поворот матрицы на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки

Tags: python

Как можно повернуть матрицу из состояния А в состояние В?
А:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
```

В:

```
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста - у вас матрица это список списков, Numpy 2D array, Pandas DataFrame или что-то другое?

Comment: Простая, список списков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проще всего будет воспользоваться Numpy:

исходная матрица:

```
import numpy as np

In [86]: l
Out[86]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

In [87]: a = np.array(l)

In [70]: a
Out[70]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

поворот:

```
In [71]: np.rot90(a)
Out[71]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

можно несколько раз повернуть:

```
In [72]: np.rot90(a, k=2)
Out[72]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

"вернуть" к обычному списку списков:

```
In [107]: np.rot90(a).tolist()
Out[107]: [[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

---

без использования Numpy:

```
In [131]: list(zip(*lst))[::-1]
Out[131]: [(0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

проверка:

```
In [140]: a
Out[140]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [141]: lst = a.tolist()

In [142]: lst
Out[142]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]

In [143]: np.rot90(a)
Out[143]:
array([[ 3,  7, 11, 15],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
       [ 1,  5,  9, 13],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12]])

In [144]: np.rot90(a).tolist()
Out[144]: [[3, 7, 11, 15], [2, 6, 10, 14], [1, 5, 9, 13], [0, 4, 8, 12]]

In [145]: list(zip(*lst))[::-1]
Out[145]: [(3, 7, 11, 15), (2, 6, 10, 14), (1, 5, 9, 13), (0, 4, 8, 12)]
```